# How to disable an item in combbox on popup show

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Is there any way to disable specific item inside combobox based on condition. which need to display on click of combobox i.e on popup show

Comment: I suspect you'll need to *owner draw* the control (to do the dimming) and then play with selection code to reject any attempt to select the item.

Comment: Actually, all items you add to a ComboBox are, in a way, *disabled*, since it's your code that does *something* with an Item selection. If you do nothing... Do you mean that an Item should *appear disabled*, visually? Or that no action is performed by your code if specific Items are *flagged* as *disabled*? Both? What is the condition? What kind of items are you adding to the ComboBox and how? What is a popup?

Comment: yes item should be appear disabled on popup based on condition

Comment: So when you load the `ComboBox` you need to disable items based on condition. Why can't you check the condition and remove the item from List before binding it to `ComboBox`. Can you just give example or screen shot or code for little more clarity.

Comment: @SH7 let say items {a1,a2} in combobox.. so condition is if a1 then disabled that a1 item in combobox on popup show.

Comment: @J_Shrestha i'm confused on popup show part. like you will select the a1 from `ComboBox` a popup appears which shows other items but not a1. ??

Comment: @SH7 nope.. we are only trying to show all items on popup when click on combobox.no need to select item only disabled a1 item but need to show in list.

Comment: ok ok got it. @J_Shrestha

Comment: @J_Shrestha refer my answer. Is that what you are looking for. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Set the property `DrawMode` of the `ComboBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed`

Step 2. Change the Item color using Index value

```
 Font fontValue = new Font("calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular);

 //Form Load
 private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    List<string> lstCombxValue = new List<string>();
    lstCombxValue.Add("Item A1");
    //Item to Disable
    lstCombxValue.Add("Item A2");
    lstCombxValue.Add("Item A3");
    lstCombxValue.Add("Item A4");
    lstCombxValue.Add("Item A5");
    lstCombxValue.Add("Item A6");

    comboBox1.DataSource = lstCombxValue;
 }

 private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
 {
     //Check the Condition get the Item Index Value to Disable 
     //and follow this step to disable the item
     if (e.Index == 1)
     {
         e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), fontValue, Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
     }
     else
     {
         e.DrawBackground();
         e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), fontValue, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
         e.DrawFocusRectangle();
     }
 }
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Use `e.Font` as the Font argument, otherwise the Combo items won't be drawn correctly. You should also use the `e.ForeColor` value as the Item color, otherwise, in general, the ComboBox won't match the styles set in the Designer.